# Using C to fire rules

Tags: c, makefile, rules

Im trying to set up a few functions in C where the program can read a specific rule and "fire" it depending on the date of the files. My problem is that while the function is working, the results are not right.

To put it in perspective, the program is imitating as a 'make' file. this 'make' file is meant to read some inputs through optarg(the input name, and the process), and then process the rules through another function. after that, the program simply checks the last date modified of the targets and the dependencies and 'fires' them depending on the dates.

The function itself needs to fire the rules if needed, but they are not working with the tests that I am using. Switching the condition around seemed to provide some result until I noticed that it was intentionally setting off unnecessary rules.

What should I consider in this case when im modifying my code to make it work? Do I need to alter the conditions again, or add more variables.

```
bool detectrules(struct stat *filea, struct stat *fileb){
double check = difftime(filea->st_mtime,fileb->st_mtime);
if (check > 0) return 1;
else return 0;
} 

void comparerules(Rule *rulea){
int VALUE= 0;
struct stat TargetA;
struct stat DependA;
while(1){
    if(rulea[VALUE].targets == NULL) break;
    VALUE++;
        }
    VALUE--;
    while(1){
        if(VALUE < 0) break;
        TargetA.st_mtime = 0;           
        stat (rulea[VALUE].targets[0], &TargetA);
        int m = 0;
        while(1){
            if(rulea[VALUE].depends[m] == NULL){
                m = 0;
                break;
            }
            DependA.st_mtime = 0;
            stat (rulea[VALUE].depends[m], &DependA);
            if(detectrules(&TargetA, &DependA) == 1){
            printf("Fire rule %i \n",VALUE+1);
            break;
            }
            m++;
        }
        VALUE--;
    }
}
```

Comment: On which operating system? If on Linux, use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) if your program is working on files. In all cases, compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`). Improve the code to get no warnings. Use the debugger (`gdb`) to run the program step by step and query its state. Test that your syscalls (notably `stat`) are successful, so carefully read their man page (e.g. [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html)...) before coding.

Comment: Please **edit your question** to improve it (BTW, your question is currently off-topic and will be closed soon). Don't comment it.

Comment: BTW, if your program is some "imitation" of `make` you'll better study -for inspiration- the source code of [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) which is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software). But -assuming it is some homework- do be honest with your teacher (I guess he *wants* you to study existing free software code).